# Obtaining the "Name" of the StringOffset from the WinAPI ReadEventLog()

Tags: c++, winapi, event-viewer, readeventlog

I am using the Windows API to get recent events from the Windows Event Viewer. Everything is working great so far but I am confused as to how I determine the `StringOffset` field. I iterated through and created an array of the strings that exist in that buffer but there is no context associated with each string.

Having a look at the Windows Event Viewer, I see in raw XML that there is a field name that you don't get in the API (at least none that I am aware of).

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ProcessID">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="Application">System</Data> 
  <Data Name="Direction">%%14592</Data> 
  <Data Name="SourceAddress">192.168.22.232</Data> 
  <Data Name="SourcePort">137</Data> 
  <Data Name="DestAddress">192.168.22.255</Data> 
  <Data Name="DestPort">137</Data> 
  <Data Name="Protocol">17</Data> 
  <Data Name="FilterRTID">71247</Data> 
  <Data Name="LayerName">%%14610</Data> 
  <Data Name="LayerRTID">44</Data> 
  <Data Name="RemoteUserID">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="RemoteMachineID">S-1-0-0</Data> 
</EventData>
```

The documentation begins here:

[EVENTLOGRECORD structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363646.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `StringOffset` is a fixed field of the `EVENTLOGRECORD` struct that you read from the log.  It contains a byte offset from the beginning of the record to the string data. MSDN has an example ([Querying for Event Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356.aspx)) showing that field in use. What are you missing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau My question is, is how do I know what field is what? Like you said, they provide the data but no context to the data. So, rather having `<Data Name="DestPort">137</Data>`, it is just `137`. How do I know that's the port?

Comment: *"How do I know that's the port?"* - Easy: You don't. XML defines the syntax, not the semantics. If you need to understand the semantics, you have to ask the creator of that specific log entry.

Comment: The content of `EventData` is event-specific, defined by the app that logged the event

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `Security` log is for system use only. Meaning, the only source writing to it is Windows. I figured out how to get the context regarding the EventData field in the API.